# Form not submitted in laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I want to submit the form to usercontroller file and call function invitebyemail.

When I click on submit it gives me error like "Whoops, looks like something went wrong."

Below are the structure of my Files and code.

Route File:

```
Route::POST('event/inviteforevent', 'UserController@invitebyemail');
```

Blade.php file

```
    <form action="{{ route('inviteforevent') }}" method="POST">
    <input type="email" class="form-control full-width" id="add-members-event-email" name="email" placeholder="Email address">
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control full-width" name="eventid" value="{{ $event->id }}" >
    <input type="submit" name="invite" value="submit" />
    </form>
```

UserController File:

```
public function invitebyemail(Request $request){        
 $event = Event::find($request->eventid);
 $timelineId = $event->timeline_id;
 $username = Auth::user()->username;
 $timelines = Timeline::find($timelineId);
  return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Invitation send to user by email.');
 }
```

Comment: Pro-tip: enable debugging through your `.env` file to get meaningful error messages, instead of "Whoops, something went wrong". (Assuming you're using v5+)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `route()` helper function expects a route name.

```
Route::post('event/inviteforevent', 'UserController@invitebyemail')->name('inviteforevent');
```

**Edit**

Run `php artisan serve` and access your server at `http://localhost:8000`. You have not set the web root and laravel url rewrite won't work properly along with the `url` and `route` methods generating wrong links.

Comment: I did this but not its not working."Route::post('event/inviteforevent', 'UserController@invitebyemail')->name('inviteforevent');"

Comment: Run `php artisan route:clear` once. Also check the link generated in form action when you load the page.

Comment: Form Link like this "expats_adworlds/public/event/inviteforevent"

Comment: @GauravSharna check my edited answer. You need to run your server with `php artisan serve`.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the Route change that was suggested, you may need to add the

`{{ csrf_field() }}`

after

`<form action="{{ route('inviteforevent') }}" method="POST">`

Read more here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf#csrf-introduction

Comment: have you also changed the Route as suggested below?
Are the other pages working?
Could you please enable logs and upload the full error?

Comment: TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68. Error Message.

Comment: ok, add the {{ csrf_field() }} as mentioned above and check that the following code is in your <head>..</head>
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

Answer (score 0):

change

```
Route::POST('event/inviteforevent', 'UserController@invitebyemail');
```

to

```
Route::POST('event/inviteforevent', 'UserController@invitebyemail')->name("inviteforevent");
```

Reference : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#named-routes

Answer (score 0):

Please replace this code in route:-

```
Route::post('event/inviteforevent', 'UserController@invitebyemail')->name('inviteforevent');
```

OR

```
 Route::post('event/inviteforevent', ['as' => 'inviteforevent',  uses' => 'UserController@invitebyemail']);
```

Comment: Done this but again same issue.

Comment: So doing php artisan cache:clear , php artisan route:clear , php artisan optimize, php artisan  config:clear

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `{{ csrf_field() }}` which was suggested but one question? Where is your table names and id in your form opening? How that form have to know which table you want to add data in?
You have to add `$events` and `$events->id` into your form